# snapd version installed via package manager and snapd version displayed by snap --version are not the same

Tags: snap, solus

I'm using solus, the installed version of snapd according to software centre is 2.57.5-72 but snap --version shows snapd version as 2.51. any idea on how to sync the two? (I need >2.55 to install zoom-client)